# Function Get Object in foxpro 2.6

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Could someone brief me about full structure format for All function GET object (as example like belows) or any websites could refer on it.

@ 3,5 GET vn_tick FUNCTION '*R Screen;Print;Export to PDF' default 1

@ 10,6 GET vn_choice FUNCTION '*TH OK;CANCEL' DEFAULT 1 SIZE 2,8 COLOR 12,15,,,,W+/GR,R/B,,GR+/B,W/B

The information for this kind of Function GET object is quite useful for me but it is quite harder to find over google when I've failed to attempt find. Thanks appropriate to someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's listed in the FoxPro 2.6 and Visual FoxPro help documentation.

If you're using Visual FoxPro then forget about @ SAY ..GET and do it properly with a form class. Those functions are only there for backwards compatibility with FoxPro 2.6.

Comment: Yeah, FPW2.6 is so old, they don't even describe it in the current help other than supported for backwards compat.

Answer (score 0):

The @Get with Function "*R" is associated with a radio button control, listing whatever choices you have and setting the default to the (in this case), the first choice which is screen.

The @Get with Function "*TH" is for a command GROUP of buttons, listing the buttons separated by ";" similarly defaulting to the first button "OK".  Clicking on a button will return the numeric value corresponding to the available choices... 1 = Ok, 2 = Cancel.

Don't know where you might actually find that old of documentation though.

Comment: @koklimabc, you are welcome... Also, take a look at Help -> Tour for site etiquette.  It helps for others having similar issues know what worked vs not.

Answer (score 0):

The updated help file on VFPx contains all of the descriptions from the FP2.6 help file. That's what I use.

[VFP 9 SP2 Help File](http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VFP%209%20SP2%20Help%20File&referringTitle=Home)

Note: The content in the help file for the GET command is huge so I don't want to paste it all here.